# Adding third monitor to desktop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

For the last 2 years I have been running a dual monitor setup, but I want to change to a three monitor setup.

My dual monitor setup was my Skylake igpu. One monitor on HDMI and one monitor on VGA. Now to add a third monitor I put a Geforce 7300LE GPU into my desktop and I am trying to make this work. Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I know there are more questions here on this topic, but those answers where not able to help me.

After I installed the nvidia-304 driver I am able to see the monitor in the displays dialog. But unfortunately my monitor does only gave a black screen. It sends a signal cause my monitor does not go in sleep mode. I can also move the mouse pointer to the monitor, but it isn't displayed on the monitor.

I know the third monitor is able to display cause at one time only the third monitor displayed my gui (but I had a problem with a login screen loop).

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Kind Regards,
Emiel

Comment: I just discovered that when taking a screenshot, for example with no programs opened, that the screenshot displays three empty desktops. Including wallpaper and menubar, 3 copies of my empty DE.